# How to resize a website which appears in an iFrame?

Tags: facebook, iframe, web, resize, scrollbar

How can we resize a website which appears in an iFrame ? Is it possible if the website is wider than the Facebook page to make it appear a bit smaller so that we can see it all ?
Here is the code I used to avoid the scroll bar at least:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe style="width:827px; height:1000px;" src="#"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 0):

Change the height and width for example for my facebook i changed it to 
`style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:215px; height:290px;"` 
Just make sure to add the overflow hidden part so it hides any extra

Comment: I tried to change the width and the height but the page is seen (I would say) "under" the white facebook page. When I try to change the width, it doesn't change the size of my website page but only modify the size of the white facebook page. (I'm using iFrame Apps)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code just after your opening  tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId : 'YOUR APP ID', //Your facebook APP here
          cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        });
      }

      window.onload = function() {
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(91);
      }
    </script>
```

also add this css statement to your header section.

```
<style>
body {overflow:hidden;} /*This is handy for removing horizontal/vertical scrollbars as we won't need them if we autosize; */
</style>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I'm using iFrame APPS. Is there a solution for that ?